# jQuery get img source attributes from list and push into array

Tags: jquery, arrays, loops, attributes, push

I have this thumbnail list and would like push the image paths (sources) into an array: tn_array

```
<ul id="thumbnails">
    <li><img src="somepath/tn/004.jpg" alt="fourth caption" /></a></li>
    <li><img src="somepath/tn/005.jpg" alt="fifth caption" /></a></li>
    <li><img src="somepath/tn/006.jpg" alt="sixth caption" /></a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 48, accepted):

You can create the array of src attributes more directly using [`map()`](http://api.jquery.com/map/):

```
var tn_array = $("#thumbnails img").map(function() {
  return $(this).attr("src");
});
```

**Edit:** `tn_array` is an object here rather than a strict Javascript array but it will act as an array. For example, this is legal code:

```
for (int i=0; i<tn_array.length; i++) {
  alert(tn_array[i]);
}
```

You can however call [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get/), which will make it a strict array:

```
var tn_array = $("#thumbnails img").map(function() {
  return $(this).attr("src");
}).get();
```

How do you tell the difference? Call:

```
alert(obj.constructor.toString());
```

The first version will be:

```
function Object() { [native code] }
```

The second:

```
function Array() { [native code] }
```

Comment: Yes, thanks +1.  I was looking for a similar technique to get an array of val().  Kind of surprising jquery doesn't have something built in for this.  Seems like a quibble, but it is, after all, the "write less" library. :)

Comment: Also remember that if you want an actual array, you need to call .get() on the result of .map().

Answer (score 5):

You can loop through ever `img` element:

```
var tn_array = Array();

$('#thumbnails img').each(function() {
    tn_array.push($(this).attr('src'));
});
```