# Why does typeof my_var return undefined when my_var is assigned to map() function?

Tags: jquery, dictionary

I came across this post:

[jQuery get img source attributes from list and push into array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2355025/jquery-get-img-source-attributes-from-list-and-push-into-array)

Which introduced me to the [map()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.map/) function.

Say I am getting the images `src` for multiple images via:

```
var $img_sources_array = $(".my_class img").map(function() {
return $(this).attr("src");
});
```

When I use `typeof $img_sources_array` in Firebug console, I get "undefined".

But if I do:

```
$.each($img_sources_array, function (obj,v) {
alert(v);
});
```

Then each image source is shown.

*Question*

So what type is `$img_sources_array`, what does it 'look like', and how can I access its values from the console?

*Context*

I am trying to understand the structure of what is returned so that I can work up to constructing multidimensional arrays where I could add and access `src` and `class` with something like:

```
var my_object_array = [];

var $img_properties_array_2 = $(".image_container img").map(function() {
var img_src = $(this).attr("src");
var img_class = $(this).attr("class");
var my_object = {};
my_object.img_src = img_src;
my_object.img_class = img_class;
my_object_array.push(my_object);
});

console.log(my_object_array[0].img_class); // this works, type fixed in array name
```

**jsFiddle**

http://jsfiddle.net/rwone/tD9eh/7/

**Edit:**   In regards to the second part of the question, the following returns what I was after:

```
// container for multidimensional arrays
var my_object_array = [];

var $img_properties_array_2 = $(".image_container img").map(function() {
var img_src = $(this).attr("src");
var img_class = $(this).attr("class");
var my_object = {};
my_object.img_src = img_src;
my_object.img_class = img_class;
my_object_array.push(my_object);
}); 

$.each(my_object_array, function (obj,v) {
console.log('image source: ' + v.img_src);
console.log('image class: ' + v.img_class);
});
```

Comment: You misspelled your array name at the bottom. This is also not really the ideal way to use `map()`.

Comment: yes, thanks, i just saw that and corrected it.

Comment: In your code you are accessing `my_object_array`, but in the text you are asking about `$img_sources_array`. What is it now? I can tell you that `$img_sources_array` is an empty jQuery object, because a) `.map` returns a jQuery object and be b) you are not returning anything from the `.map` callback. You might want to read again what the purpose of `.map` is: http://api.jquery.com/map/

Answer (score 1):

`.map()` just group the returned value/object, Additionally you have to use `.get()` to convert that into an array.

Try,

```
var my_object_array = $(".image_container img").map(function() {
   var img_src = $(this).attr("src");
   var img_class = $(this).attr("class");
   var my_object = {};
   my_object.img_src = img_src;
   my_object.img_class = img_class;
   return my_object;
}).get();
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/tD9eh/4/)

Comment: Why should the OP try that? Code without and **explanation** is not an answer.